# Excel 2016 Conditional-Format Cells that are Data-Validated

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have searched thoroughly and cannot find this specific problem.

I will first describe a working case followed by a non-working case, and I think that will describe the problem I am trying to solve.

**Working case: Conditional Format Cells that contain a formula:**

1 - I have Defined Name "ccell" which refers to "=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())"

- It returns the Address of the current cell

2 - I have Defined Name "ccellval" which refers to "=INDIRECT(ccell)"

- It returns the value of the current cell

3 - I have defined name "_IsFormula" which refers to "=ISFORMULA(ccellvalue)"

- It returns a Boolean flagging that the current cell contains a formula

4 - I have a Conditional Format that uses the formula "=_IsFormula" and is applied at row level (e.g. applied to "1:10000")

The expected behaviour is that any time I enter a formula to a cell, that cell changes format - and it works perfectly.

**Non-Working case: Conditional Format Cells with a Data Validation**

1 - I use the existing Defined Name "ccell" mentioned above

- It returns the Address of the current cell

2 - I have a UDF to return a Boolean if a cell is Data-Validated:

```
Public Function Validated (ThisCell As Range) As Boolean    
Dim v: v = Null    
On Error Resume Next    
v = ThisCell.Validation.Type    
On Error GoTo 0    
Validated = Not IsNull(v)    
End Function
```

I have tested this UDF in-cell and it supplies the result TRUE when the cell is data-validated and #VALUE! when it is not.

3 - I have defined name "_IsValidated" which refers to "=Validated(ccell)"

- I intend this to apply my UDF to the current cell = ccell

4 - I have a Conditional Format that uses the formula "=_IsValidated" and is applied at row level (e.g. applied to "1:10000")

The expected behaviour is that any time I add data validation to a cell, that cell changes format - and it does not work.

I have tried various permutations, such as embedding ccell into my "Validated" UDF instead of into "_IsValidated" defined name.

What am I trying to achieve with this? I am writing templates for users, and I want cells coloured as a visual aid.

Any pointers / ideas would be gratefully received :) Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of what `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` returns. 
`ADDRESS` returns a `String` containing the cell address. And `INDIRECT` does not return a cell value but a cell reference. That's why your name `ccellval` should better be `ccellref`.

Your `UDF` `Public Function Validated (ThisCell As Range) As Boolean` needs `ThisCell` as `Range` (as a reference to a cell) but you are handing over `ccell` which is a `String`.

So:

1 - Use the existing Defined Name "ccell" mentioned above

- It returns the Address of the current cell as a `String`

2 - Have Defined Name "ccellref" which refers to "=INDIRECT(ccell)"

- It returns the **reference** of the current cell

3 - Have your UDF to return a Boolean if a cell is Data-Validated.

4 - Have defined name "_IsValidated" which refers to "=Validated(ccellref)"

5 - Have a Conditional Format that uses the formula "=_IsValidated"

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. Actually, there was a subtlety in the final answer which I will briefly describe: I originally did refer to the 'INDIRECT' function in order to return a Reference.  Embarrassingly, the problem turned out to be that my conditional format, which was set to "=_IsValidated()" should be "=_IsValidated" - i.e. the empty brackets were not required. So, your reply helped me to find the true error, because you verified what I already believed was correct - so I looked again step by step for the error. Greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: And - now it is working as intended - it is clear to me that the volatile Data Validation UDF is using a lot of RAM and the user experience is now somewhat laggy. I will try to find a cleaner UDF or a method of not requiring a UDF - perhaps an old XLM formula or something